# convert byte array to string, string can't convert back after transfer

Tags: java, android, string, arrays, converters

Code for the same:

```
public byte[] stringToBytesUTFCustom(String str) {
    char[] buffer1 = str.toCharArray();
    byte[] b = new byte[buffer1.length << 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer1.length; i++) {
        int bpos = i << 1;
        b[bpos] = (byte) ((buffer1[i]&0xFF00)>>8);
        b[bpos + 1] = (byte) (buffer1[i]&0x00FF);
    }
    return b;
}
public String bytesToStringUTFCustom(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] buffer = new char[bytes.length >> 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        int bpos = i << 1;
        char c = (char)(((bytes[bpos]&0x00FF)<<8) + (bytes[bpos+1]&0x00FF));
        buffer[i] = c;
    }
    String txt = String.valueOf(buffer);
    //return new String(buffer);
    return txt;
}
```

First, I implement a SMS encryption app (Client to Client) and then want to encode cipher(format "Byte[]") to string, Base64 it's work but can't send because more than 160 character.
I'm want to convert byte array to string ,when use function above it's work for same function, but when I use bytesToStringUTFCustom and then send this text(SMS) can't work.
Receiver cannot read a text to decode from.

Cipher is a result of bytesToStringUTFCustom function, so anyone can help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you know these:

- [`String.getBytes(Charset encoding)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`new String(byte[] byteArray, Charset encoding)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can use [`Charset.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the Charset.

```
Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(UTF8);
String reverted = new String(bytes, UTF8);
```

Comment: Exactly. Why roll your own?